# Parse JSON document to records for PostgreSQL with Python

Tags: python, json, postgresql, parsing

I am trying to parse a JSON document into records to store them in PostgreSQL using Python. I am new to this. Trying to put together two strings. A header string and a value string. The structure of a JSON document with nested vocabularies is difficult.

```
# import Python's JSON lib
import json

# import the new JSON method from psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import Json

dict = {"results": [
        {
            "communication_type": "ChatSite",
            "conversation": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2021-11-26 23:30:20",
                    "id": "b29530e3-69ff-4798-abb1-abc17d4d44b5",
                    "int_referer": "link1",
                    "result": "failure",
                    "visitor_id": "account:206867:site:167330:visitor:ybrr4e43f3hj8aor"
                }
            ],
            "duration": 53,
            "first_answer_time": null
        },
        {
            "communication_type": "ChatSite",
            "conversation": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2021-11-26 23:34:00",
                    "id": "e8f7e9bf-e836-4643-a30c-8bcbeffc397a",
                    "int_referer": "link2",
                    "result": "failure",
                    "visitor_id": "account:206867:site:167330:visitor:iosbe9bfqbfswcdi"
                }
            ],
            "duration": 16,
            "first_answer_time": null
        },
    ]
}

a = list(dict.values())   
b = a[0]

# use JSON loads to create a list of records
record_list = json.loads(b)

# create a nested list of the records' values
values = [list(x.values()) for x in record_list]

# get the column names
columns = [list(x.keys()) for x in record_list][0]
##print(columns)
# value string for the SQL string
values_str = ""

# enumerate over the records' values
for i, record in enumerate(b):

    # declare empty list for values
    val_list = []
   
    # append each value to a new list of values
    for v, val in enumerate(record):
        if type(val) == str:
            val = str(Json(val)).replace('"', '')
        val_list += [ str(val) ]
      
    # put parenthesis around each record string
    values_str += "(" + ', '.join( val_list ) + "),\n"
   
# remove the last comma and end SQL with a semicolon
values_str = values_str[:-2] + ";"
#print(values_str)
# concatenate the SQL string
table_name = "json_data"
sql_string = "INSERT INTO %s (%s)\nVALUES %s" % (
    table_name,
    ', '.join(columns),
    values_str
)
print (sql_string)
```

Please help me how to fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Dev\livetex-master\Two.py", line 45, in <module>
    record_list = json.loads(b)
  File "C:\Users\ANISA4\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list
```

I am trying to output a header string like:
"communication_type", "created_at" "id" "int_referer" "result", "visitor_id", "duration", "first_answer_time"

Answer (score 0):

The dict is not a json string, you have to have it in raw format and then load it with json.loads() => json load string

```py
{
            "communication_type": "ChatSite",
            "conversation": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2021-11-26 23:30:20",
                    "id": "b29530e3-69ff-4798-abb1-abc17d4d44b5",
                    "int_referer": "link1",
                    "result": "failure",
                    "visitor_id": "account:206867:site:167330:visitor:ybrr4e43f3hj8aor"
                }
            ],
            "duration": 53,
            "first_answer_time": null
        }
```

should be

```json
"{
            "communication_type": "ChatSite",
            "conversation": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2021-11-26 23:30:20",
                    "id": "b29530e3-69ff-4798-abb1-abc17d4d44b5",
                    "int_referer": "link1",
                    "result": "failure",
                    "visitor_id": "account:206867:site:167330:visitor:ybrr4e43f3hj8aor"
                }
            ],
            "duration": 53,
            "first_answer_time": null
        }"
```

also

```py
a = list(dict.values())
```

returns list in list since your results is list
[[...data...]]

Comment: a = list(dict.values())  I took this step)

Comment: because of that you have list in `b` and that cannot be json.loads().
try to play just with json.loads() somewhere.
try 

`json.loads("[1,2]")`

and then 
`json.loads([1, 2])`